# Problema com conexão ao web service - NetworkOnMainThreadException

Tags: android, json, web-service

Estou executando um método em android, onde tento realizar a recuperar algumas informações de um webservice ... parei para depurar e sempre quando ele vai se conectar ele cai no catch e quando continua ele vai até a classe Activity Thread, na qual apresenta um monte de erros como é possivel identificar na imagem a seguir [image: Erros ao depurar]

estou utilizando o seguinte método para a conexão

```
 public String acessar(String endereco) throws IOException {
        URL url = new URL("http://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/1/");
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        urlConnection.connect();
        InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
        if (inputStream == null) {
            return null;
        }
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        String linha;
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        while ((linha = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            buffer.append(linha + "\n");
        }
        if (buffer.length() == 0) {
            return null;
        }
        if (urlConnection != null) {
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
        if (reader != null) {
            try {
                reader.close();
            } catch (final IOException e) {
                Log.e("Erro", "Erro fechando o stream", e);
            }
        }
        return "";
    }
```

E mesmo tendo todos os try e catch ele ainda para minha aplicação, qual seria o melhor método para arrumar esse problema? eu também habilitei todo acesso ha internet com relação ao manifests.

Erro que aparece:

> 08-21 13:06:37.016 3240-3240/dev.sbruno.sibcom E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL
>   EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                    Process: dev.sbruno.sibcom, PID: 3240
>                                                                    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{dev.sbruno.sibcom/dev.sbruno.sibcom.ListaCategoriaActivity}:
>   android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
>                                                                        at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
>                                                                        at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
>                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                                        at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
>                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
>                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                        at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
>                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
>                                                                     Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
>                                                                        at
>   android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1303)
>                                                                        at
>   java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupHostByName(Inet6AddressImpl.java:86)
>                                                                        at
>   java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Inet6AddressImpl.java:74)
>                                                                        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:752)
>                                                                        at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.Network$1.resolveInetAddresses(Network.java:29)
>                                                                        at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:187)
>                                                                        at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.nextProxy(RouteSelector.java:156)
>                                                                        at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:98)
>                                                                        at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.createNextConnection(HttpEngine.java:345)
>                                                                        at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:328)
>                                                                        at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:246)
>                                                                        at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:457)
>                                                                        at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:126)
>                                                                        at
>   dev.sbruno.sibcom.ListaCategoriaActivity.acessar(ListaCategoriaActivity.java:76)
>                                                                        at
>   dev.sbruno.sibcom.ListaCategoriaActivity.onCreate(ListaCategoriaActivity.java:63)
>                                                                        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
>                                                                        at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
>                                                                        at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
>                                                                        at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726) 
>                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
>                                                                        at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477) 
>                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
>                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
>                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                        at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
>                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)

Comment: Você poderia postar o stack trace do error, acho que ajudaria mais. Eu indico você usar a biblioteca RETROFIT para lidar com este tipo de requisição pois facilita bastande.

Comment: Para adicionar esse RETORFIT ao meu projeto é apenas adicionar ele ao compile, ou tenho que baixar algo e adicionar?

Comment: @BrunoAparecidodaSilva somente adicionar ao projeto, mas dá uma estudada antes em como ela funciona. Recomendaria também a Spring Android, que acho um pouco mais simples que a Retrofit. Tem a Volley também, que é do próprio Google.

Comment: Editei informando o erro que aparece

Comment: Adoro quando alguém se depara com um problema e pede ajuda as sugestões sejam: "use antes a API XY".

Comment: Não consegui resolver meu problema, então comecei a utilizar o RetroFit, em um tutorial que fiz na internet funcionou 100%, mas em minha maquina local ocorre alguns erros!. aqui está o link do novo post, se puderem me ajudar fico grato [https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/230794/problema-com-retorno-do-retrofit-em-android]