# Problema com Retorno do RetroFit em Android

Tags: android, retrofit

Estou tentando me conectar a rede local, utilizando o `RetroFit`. Na rede local tenho um Rest que retorna um json, porém quando executo o evento para que isso ocorra, acontece um erro

tenho uma classe interface para o RetroFit

```
public interface iRetroFitSibcom {

    @GET("/{categoria}")
    Call<List<Categoria>> getCategorias(@Path("categoria") String categoria); 

    public static final Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("http://10.0.2.2:8080/sibcomslim")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
}
```

E um button onde ocorre o evento

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    iRetroFitSibcom githubUser = iRetroFitSibcom.retrofit.create(iRetroFitSibcom.class);
    final Call <List<Categoria>> call = githubUser.getCategorias("categorias");
    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Categoria>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<Categoria>> call, Response<List<Categoria>> response) {
            int code = response.code();
            if (code == 200) {
                List<Categoria> lista = response.body();
                for (Categoria categoria : lista) {
                    Log.d("MainActivity", categoria.descricao);
                }
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Falha: " + String.valueOf(code),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<Categoria>> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
}
```

Porém quando faço isso nada ocorre, não me aparece mensagem de erro nem mostrando as descrições no Log.d.

Porém é carregada as seguintes informações

> 08-21 14:41:59.637 6491-6491/dev.sbruno.sibcom I/Choreographer:
>   Skipped 36 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its
>   main thread. 
>   08-21 14:42:04.622 6491-6491/dev.sbruno.sibcom
>   D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using
>   platform default 
>   08-21 14:42:17.388 6491-6496/dev.sbruno.sibcom I/art:
>   Do partial code cache collection, code=30KB, data=28KB 08-21
>   14:42:17.391 6491-6496/dev.sbruno.sibcom I/art: After code cache
>   collection, code=23KB, data=25KB 08-21 14:42:17.391
>   6491-6496/dev.sbruno.sibcom I/art: Increasing code cache capacity to
>   128KB

O que está ocorrendo de errado? mesmo tentando depurar não consigo fazer pois não é possivel acessar as linhas que coloco para depurar, ele nem chega até elas

Edit

Acabei de adicionar uma Toast no onFailure e verifiquei que o código está passando por lá, então deve haver algum erro na conexão é isso?

```
@Override
public void onFailure(Call<List<Categoria>> call, Throwable t) {
      Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Falhou ao me conectar ",
      Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: Qual é a mensagem dentro do t (Throwable)?

Comment: A mensagem do t é java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out ... DetailMessage: "connect timed out", era isso que queria saber ou quer ver todos os valores que o t retorna?

Comment: Pode ser que o seu app não esteja conseguindo se conectar ao host. Vc consegue consultar essa API de outras formas (curl, postman, etc)?

Comment: Sim leonardo, através do postman ele carrega todo o json quando eu coloco o link onde ele está http://localhost/sibcomslim/categoria